# display data angular 4 (converting obj to array)

Tags: arrays, angular, ngfor

I'm trying to display an object of an object in an array, I've been hitting my head against the wall since I cant change the backend. 
this is what I got so far, M01, M02, M03... might refer to months since we are November there are 11 however if it was February id be only M01 and M02. since I got a property of an object I cant loop it on a second for and I'm having a lot of trouble with it

[image: Array to display]

this is my view

```
<div *ngIf="estados" class="table-responsive col-lg-12 tablilla">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th *ngFor="let month of listaMonthsNames">{{month}}</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let estado of estados">
      <td>{{estado.nom_item}}</td>
      <td *ngFor="let month of estado.M[0]">{{month}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help you :

There is no direct way to access `Object` from the Template side so,

All you need to do is provide `Object.keys` access to the `Template` side by this way from `Component` :

```
// Component Side :
objectKeys = Object.keys;

// Template Side :
<td *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(estado.M)">
    Key: {{key}}, value: {{estado.M[key]}}
</td>
```

You can read more about the Object.keys [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: @RildoGomez, please go through the link once, you will get the idea.

Comment: Thank you Vivek Doshi! it needed a little change tho, it was only *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(estado.M)">{{estado.M[key]}} without [0]